# PHP Function with readfile seems no ending

Tags: php, function, download

I have a function creating a zip-file and at the end it downloads this zip-file.

here the problem:
the whole function works and it downloads the zip-file and it is usable (not broken or something) but it doesn't go on ... The formular rests there with all the input data and the php stucks ....

if I don't do the zip-download at the end everything is fine (but I don't have the zip file downloaded ...) but if I do the download at the end it stucks ...

here is the download-code:

```
public function DownloadFile($file){
try{
if(file_exists($file)){
$dateiname = basename($file);
$groesse = filesize($file);
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$dateiname);
header("Content-Length:".$groesse);
header("Location: ".$file);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
}
return TRUE;
}catch(Exception $ex){
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

anyone have an idea?

Comment: what does your **[PHP errror log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)** tell you ?

Comment: i find no error in this log. it downloads the file but nothing more happen ...